# Dynamic selector in .on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, onclick

I have some form that represents quiz creating page where I want to dynamically add questions and answers to those question. I want to respond on click event on newly created buttons.

Problem is that onClick event is executed only on first button which exists from the beginning.

Here is sample of my code. I have form with id `myForm`, div with id `questioni` that encapsulates all stuff regarding `i`-th question (also button with class `new_answer` for adding answers to that particular question), variable `curr_q` (current question I am creating).

```
$(function () {
    $("#myForm").on('click', "#question" + curr_q + " .new_answer", function () {
        alert("#question" + curr_q + " .new_answer");
        });
});
```

Here is also fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sruzic/8yt9jcqh/ (it is little bit overwhelming but problem is that when you click on existing `Create Question` then newly created `Create Answer` button is not responing while 'old' `Create Answer` alerts that selector is `question1 .new_answer` which is exactly newly created `Create Answer` button?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a function call, `foo(bar)`, then all arguments are evaluated *before* they are passed to the function. Meaning, `"#question" + curr_question + " .new_answer"` is evaluated, resulting in a string, e.g. `"#question0 .new_answer"`, and that's the value passed to `.on`. Changing  `curr_question` later on does not affect that value. It doesn't get "magically" reevaluated. Why don't you just use `.new_answer` as selector instead?

Comment: I also assumed that it is the case. Is there any possible solution to my problem?

Comment: `$("#myForm").on('click', ".new_answer", function () { ... })`.

Comment: So the problem here is that you are using ID's when you should be using classes unless to specify every possible id combination up front, this will never work.  We also need to understand the HTML structure in play here as you will likely need to be able to relate answers to questions based on their location in DOM relative to one another. Please add sample HTML to the question.

Comment: I only want to respond on events from question I am currently creating...

Comment: In that case you should probably bind the handler directly on the element. When a new element is added, unbind the handler from the previous element.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. My another idea was to show only question I am creating, while hiding all others - in that case I think that `".new_answer"` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

update your code to this . check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8yt9jcqh/3/)

```
        $(function () {
            var selector = "#question" + curr_q + " .new_question";
            $(selector).click(function () {
                curr_q++;
                alert(curr_q);
                total_q++;
                $('#myForm').append(generateQuestionSubForm(total_q))

                $("#myForm").on('click', "#question" + curr_q + " .new_answer", function () {
            alert("#question" + curr_q + " .new_answer");
                 });

            });
        });
```

Comment: I think that it works exactly as if I wrote `$("#myForm").on('click', ".new_answer", function () { ... })`

Comment: @sruzic yes this will also work .. so whats issue now ?

Comment: "I only want to respond on events from question I am currently creating..."

Comment: I is now similar to @Felix Kling comment about binding event handlers.. However, now all `Create Answers` button (except first) are clickable which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing your event listener, just remove the new_answer class from previous inputs when a new item is created. Something like this should work:

```
$(function () {
            var selector = "#question" + curr_q + " .new_question";
            $(selector).click(function () {
                curr_q++;
                alert(curr_q);
                total_q++;
                $('.new_answer').removeClass('new_answer');
                $('#myForm').append(generateQuestionSubForm(total_q))
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#myForm").on('click', ".new_answer", function () {
                alert("#question" + curr_q + " .new_answer");
            });
        });
```